# Прежде всего - вводное выражение или наречное выражение

Tags: пунктуация

Не хотела выносить как вопрос, но все же начала сомневаться... Есть два предложения, и мне кажется, обособление не нужно, т. к. "прежде всего" здесь можно заменить на "в первую очередь".

Этот тип войн связан с оружием физического типа, которое создавалось и развивалось на основе естественнонаучного знания, и прежде всего физики.

В современных условиях Запад, и прежде всего США и Федеральная Резервная Система, нефтедоллар ведут агрессивную неоколониальную энергетическую войну против России на всем постсоветском пространстве и за ее пределами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно, "и прежде всего" выступает в роли присоединительного союза перед обособленным оборотом.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно верно, обособление не нужно.